# Does service management API of azure also works for windows azure pack?

Tags: java, azure

I have a code which uses public API's(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460799.aspx) of Azure.
Does these API's work for windows azure pack(http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn296435.aspx) as well ?

Comment: Documentation (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn296435.aspx) states that it supports Service Management API so I guess the answer is yes. What have you tried and what problems you're facing?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn448694.aspx
I cannot see any similarity between the API's

I was trying to avoid setting up Azure pack locally. That is the reason why i asked the question here. Seems i have no other option now

Comment: You're correct. I personally haven't used Azure Pack thus I just went by the word "Service Management API" and thought they would be the same as available in Windows Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Azure Pack lets you host your own Private cloud and lets you run workloads in your own Datacenter in-premise. Not all services available on Windows Azure are available on Windows Azure Pack. Right now, it only has Web Sites, Service Bus, SQL, MySQL and IaaS services. the APIs are "consistent" with Windows Azure. it is almost exactly the same for WebSites and Service Bus but it is "similar" for IaaS and Databases. Going forward, Im guessing the goals is to ensure complete consistency such that when you build something for Windows Azure, you should be able to run it on your on-premise cloud.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When you say '"similar" for IaaS and Databases'. Can you please point me to your source. have you worked with Windows Azure pack APIs before ?